# How to make F12 invoke a render tab and not open a new window?

Tags: rendering, interface

The new window opening is annoying and I would prefer to just see the render progress in the render tab.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you go to:

*Edit > Preferences > Interface*,

under the *Editors* drop down there is another drop down called *Temporary Windows*. If you open this drop down, you will see a setting for *Render in*. If you change this to image editor, instead of it opening a new window it will change your editor type to image editor.

[image]